# ASP Classic putting byte[] Request.BinaryRead into database

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Let me start by saying I am fairly new to this and sorry if its obvious I have been trying to find an answer for a couple of days!

I am trying to insert a byte[] into a varbinary in my database but am hitting a brick wall, so I hope someone can help. So far I have:

```
Dim biData, matchId
Dim sConnString, connection, recordset, sql, count

biData = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
matchId = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")

sql = "SELECT * FROM MatchData WHERE matchId= '" & matchId & "'"

'define the connection string, specify database
'driver and the location of database
sConnString="Driver={SQL Server};<CONNECTIONSTRING>"

Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

'Open the connection to the database
connection.Open(sConnString)

'Open the recordset object executing the SQL 
recordset.Open sql, connection,3,3

count=recordset.recordcount

If count > 0 Then
    response.Write("Found  ")
    recordset.Update "MatchId", matchId

    'MY PROBLEM IS HERE
    'recordset.Update "MatchData", biData
    'recordset.Fields("MatchData").AppendChunk biData
Else
    response.Write("Not Found  ")
    recordset.AddNew "MatchId", matchId

    'MY PROBLEM IS ALSO HERE
    'recordset.Update "MatchData", biData       
    'recordset.Fields("MatchData").AppendChunk(biData)
End If

recordset.Close
Set recordset=Nothing

'Done. Close the connection object
connection.Close
Set connection = Nothing
```

If I just return the biData then I see the exact byte[] I uploaded so I guess its there i.e.
    response.BinaryWrite biData

Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the binary (chunks) in a loop:

Check this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678200(v=vs.85).aspx

Paricularly this part of the code for how to do it:

```
Cnxn.Execute "INSERT publishers(pub_id, pub_name) VALUES('" & _
               strPubID & "','Your Test Publisher')"

' Add a new record, copying the logo in chunks
rstPubInfo.AddNew
rstPubInfo!pub_id = strPubID
rstPubInfo!pr_info = strPRInfo

lngOffset = 0 ' Reset offset
Do While lngOffset < lngLogoSize
    varChunk = LeftB(RightB(varLogo, lngLogoSize - lngOffset), _
        conChunkSize)
    rstPubInfo!logo.AppendChunk varChunk
    lngOffset = lngOffset + conChunkSize
Loop
rstPubInfo.Update
```